# Unwanted shared session

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have 3 sites:

- bbb.aaa.com
- ccc.bbb.aaa.com
- ddd.bbb.aaa.com

In this scenario, if the sites are on the same server, in IE (and only in IE) all the sites have the same php session id. This means that somehow the session is shared between them.
I do not want this behavior, I'd like them to have separated sessions.

Can someone provide me any explanation for this and any advice for handling this?

(If I had domains without the aaa part, everything would work well.)

Comment: why, idk, how to counter it, build your own session Ids including hashed HOST in it

Comment: what is version of IE you using, does this happen on Edge also?

Comment: I was thinking of generating it myself, but it's not an easy task to do it reliably and test it through thoroughly. A collusion would be fatal in these systems.
I was hoping that I can manage to solve this without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the session name, from the default `PHPSESSID` to a custom name for each sites. You can do it with `session_name`:

```
// change the session name for bbb.aaa.com
session_name('PHPSESSID_bbb_aaa_com');
```

It will be used that name to create a cookie name, unique for each domain.

Then you can change the `domain` attribute of the cookie for each domain. You can do it by changing the `session.cookie_domain` on your php.ini file.

```
; instead of allows all the subdomain with ".aaa.com", specify them with:
session.cookie_domain = bbb.aaa.com
```

You can also do it at runtime with `session_set_cookie_params`.

However, **this isn't enough**! If the session id is the same, even if you used different session names, the same data will be loaded, *if the session informations are stored in a shared folder*. To solve this problem, you can change the `session.save_path` configuration directive to an unique folder for each domain. You can do it at runtime with `session_save_path`:

```
session_save_path('/path/to/sess_for_bbb_aaa_com');
```